# Create a folder based on date (YYYY-MM) using Data Factory?

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-data-factory

I have few set of monthly files dropping in my data lake folder and I want to copy them to a different folder in the data lake and while copying the data to the target data lake folder, I want to create a folder in the format YYYY-MM (Ex: 2022-11) and I want to copy the files inside this folder.

And again in the next month I will get new set of data and I want to copy them to (2022-12) folder and so on.

I want to run the pipeline every month because we will get monthly load of data.

Comment: How your file name looks like? does it has any date structure?

Comment: How are you going to identify that your existing files from a particular month? Are there any criteria that you have for that?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, My file names looks like this XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.09162022.txt.zip and I will be archiving the previous month files to a different folder, so that the data lake folder contains only the new data.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to copy only the new files using the ADF every month,
This can be done in two ways.

**First will be using a Storage event trigger.**

**Demo:**

I have created pipeline parameters like below for new file names.

[image]

Next create a storage event trigger and give the `@triggerBody().fileName` for the pipeline parameters.

[image]

Parameters:

[image]

Here I have used two parameters for better understanding. If you want, you can do it with single pipeline parameter also.

**Source dataset with dataset parameter for filename:**

[image]

**Sink dataset with dataset parameter for Folder name and filename:**

[image]

**Copy source:**

[image]

**Copy sink:**

Expression for foldername: `@formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM')`

[image]

File copied to required folder successfully when I uploaded to source folder.

[image]

So, every time a new file uploaded to your folder it gets copied to the required folder. If you don't want the file to be exist after copy, use delete activity to delete source file after copy activity.

**NOTE:** Make sure you publish all the changes before triggering the pipeline.

**Second method** can be using Get Meta data activity and ForEach and copy activity inside ForEach.

Use schedule trigger for this for every month.

First use **Get Meta data**(use another source dataset and give the path only till folder) to get the child Items and in the **filter by Last modified of Meta data activity give your month starting date in UTC(use dynamic content `utcnow()` and `FormatDatetime()` for correct format)**.

Now you will get all the list of child Items array which have last modified date as this month. Give this **array to ForEach and inside ForEach use copy activity**.

In copy activity source, use dataset parameter for file name (same as above) and give `@item().name`.

In copy activity sink, use two dataset parameters, one for Folder name and another for file name.
In Folder name give the same dynamic content for `yyyy-MM` format as above and for file name give as `@item().name`.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thanks for the solution , How do we implement the same solution if our source is a SFTP Server ?

Comment: First use copy activity to copy SFTP to ADLS before this for every month then you can use this approach as source changes to ADLS.