# Reading folders with Date format (YYYY-MM) using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, dataset, azure-data-factory

I have few folders inside the Data lake (Example:Test1 container) that are created every month in this format YYYY-MM (Example:2022-11) and inside this folder I have few set of data files, I want to copy this data files to different folders in the data lake.

And again in the next month new folder is created in the same data lake (Example:Test1 container) with 2022-12 and list goes on, 2023-01.....etc., I want to copy files inside these folders every month to different data lake folder.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is mentioned in this thread, [Create a folder based on date (YYYY-MM) using Data Factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74545918/create-a-folder-based-on-date-yyyy-mm-using-data-factory)

Follow the Sink Dataset section and Copy Sink section....remove the parameter sinkfilename from the dataset, and use this dataset as source in the copy activity.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach. For reading folders with Date format as (YYYY-MM)

I reproduce the same in my environment with copy activity.

- Open sink dataset and create a parameter with **Name: `Folder`**.

[image]

[image]

Go to Connection and Add this dynamic content: `@dataset().folder`

[image]

> **You can Add this dynamic content:**

`@concat(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy/MM'))`

**Or**

```
@concat(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy'), '/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM')
```

[image]

> **Pipeline successfully executed and got the output:**

[image]